# Custom Data type - how to add implicit conversions and math operator capability

Tags: vb.net, variables, types, decimal

My code uses almost exclusively 8 decimal place variables. Because of the rounding issues with Double variable type I have to use x=Math.Round(x,8) after every calculation to get correct results.

I could use a class for a variable type to support only 8 decimal places, however I have to refer to all instances using the .var class property which is untidy.

Is there a better way to implement this ?

```
Public Class Double8
        Private localval As Double
        Public Sub New()
            localval = 0
        End Sub
        Property var As Double
            Get
                Return localval
            End Get
            Set(value As Double)
                localval = Math.Round(value, 8)
            End Set
        End Property
End Class

'Test rounding from below, at and above .....5
Dim n As New Double8
n.var = 0.123456789
MsgBox("0.123456789 stored as " & n.var.ToString)
n.var = 0.123456782
MsgBox("0.123456782 stored as " & n.var.ToString)
n.var = 0.123456785
MsgBox("0.123456785 stored as " & n.var.ToString)
```

What I want to do is use the type `Double8` in the same manner as one would the intrinsic data types in terms of assignment with implicit conversion and perform basic math operations (add, subtract, divide, multiply) with the type with out having to refer to the type's `var` property.

Comment: This isn't really a question, as far as the Stack Overflow definition goes. You may want to try the Code Review sister site?

Comment: What about `Decimal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define both conversion operators and mathematical operators for you `Double8` type.  I have converted your `Double8` to a structure because it makes more sense for something that represents a special case of `Double`.  I have only implemented conversion to/from `Double` and addition/subtraction with `Double`.  The other operators are up to you to implement.

```
Public Structure Double8
    Private localval As Double

    Property var As Double
        Get
            Return localval
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            localval = Math.Round(value, 8)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(d As Double) As Double8
        Return New Double8 With {.var = d}
    End Operator

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(d8 As Double8) As Double
        Return d8.var
    End Operator

    Public Shared Operator +(d8 As Double8, d As Double) As Double
        Return d8.var + d
    End Operator

    Public Shared Operator -(d8 As Double8, d As Double) As Double
        Return d8.var - d
    End Operator
End Structure
```

The conversion operators (`CType`) will allow assignment between types.
`Dim d8 As Double8 = 1.123456789#`

The others operators (math and logical) will allow your types use in equations.

```
Dim d1 As Double = 5.0 + d8
Dim d2 As Double8 = d8 - 5.0
```

see:

[How to: Define a Conversion Operator (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf7b9sy7.aspx)

[How to: Define an Operator (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scs11cxx.aspx)

Comment: Thats great, I wasn't aware of this method